# Loadable Components + SSR + Webpack 5 - duplicate main.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I refactor an old application made by 'create-react-app'. I wanted to add the loadable components library and everything worked until I added **extractor.getScriptTags()** to index.html.

Adding the extractor resulted in the duplicate of the generated main.js file by the webpack

**head section** in index.html:

```
<link data-chunk="main" rel="preload" as="script" href="/main.js">
<link data-chunk="main" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.52fc8570.css">
<script defer="defer" src="/main.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.52fc8570.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**body section** with script injected via extractor.getScriptTags()

```
<script async data-chunk="main" src="/main.js"></script>
```

the fragment generated at the beginning of building the application

```
<script defer="defer" src="/main.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.52fc8570.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is it possible to disable injection of the generated main.js by the webpack?